# Value Error :Time data '2019-03-19T07:01:02Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

Tags: python, django, date

I am using dateformat function but when i search for feb month only it shows proper data but when i search for march month it shows error and this is my timedate `"date_joined": "2019-02-13T07:57:10.276212Z"` which i want to format

```
Feb month date :"date_joined": "2019-02-13T07:57:10.276212Z",
march month date : "date_joined": "2019-03-18T08:19:55.297908Z",
dates are same but when i search i got this error on march month
```

This is my separate dateformat.py file in templatetag folder

```
from django.template import Library
import datetime

register = Library()

@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def dateformat(value):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

and this is my table data line

```
<td>{{x.date_joined| dateformat|date:'d-m-Y' }}</td>
```

Error:

```
ValueError at /
time data '2019-03-19T07:01:02Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Comment: The `.%f` is too much.

Comment: As suggested, retrieved date and its format description do not match. You can chose to adjust the format or the date. I think it is easier to clean the date appending a `.0` to match with `%f` rather than maintaining different date masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%f is used for microsecond precision. But your time data "2019-03-19T07:01:02Z" doesn't have microseconds. Please change your code as:

```
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True)
def dateformat(value):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(value,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

This would work!